# minTimeout is greater than maxTimeout

Tags: macos, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have tried to create new vue-nativescript project from scratch but got this

```
$ tns run ios
Searching for devices...
Copying template files...
minTimeout is greater than maxTimeout
$
```

Comment: Do you have any options set in package lock file?

Comment: there is no package-lock.json as I start ```$ tns create app``` in completely empty folder or you are talking about file located somewhere else?